# MKMapview Coordinates UTM32

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, android-mapview, coordinate-systems

I´m getting coordinates from a JSON feed, I get them in UTM32. Does anyone know how I can convert these into latitudes and longitudes so I can display them in my mapview ?

Ex: "Lat": 597355,
    "Lng": 6643184,

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small library in Java: 
[UTM32_converter](https://github.com/kjella/UTM32_converter)

It's the result from converting a JavaScript found here: [Geo UTM](http://home.hiwaay.net/~taylorc/toolbox/geography/geoutm.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a library such as [PROJ](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) or [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/) to do the conversion from UTM to latitude/longitude. You might also consider [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/), but the UTM conversion API is basically a wrapper for PROJ, and it's a pretty large library that's probably overkill for simple conversions.

Comment: is there any easier way? Do you know if there´s a third party library written in objective c i could use?